# PayPal Checkout in ReactJs (adding different payment options)

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment, npm-package, paypal-buttons

I'm working on implementing PayPal Checkout into my ReactJs project. I'm using the npm package for react-paypal (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) but I've been unable to add additional price options. I need my dropdown options menu to connect to the PayPal checkout popup summary. The goal is to display the correct amount that the user selects in the dropdown menu to display on the PayPal checkout popup window when they click the button. I have the Paypal button displaying but it's only displaying the hard-coded "$2" that I have added for testing (I have included a couple pics). Appreciate any advice on how to add this feature.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { PayPalScriptProvider, 
PayPalButtons,usePayPalScriptReducer } from "@paypal/react- 
paypal-js";


// This values are the props in the UI
const amount = 2;
const currency = "USD";
const style = {"layout":"vertical"};

const ButtonWrapper = ({ currency, showSpinner }) => {
    const [{ options, isPending }, dispatch] = 
usePayPalScriptReducer();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: "resetOptions",
            value: {
                ...options,
                currency: currency,
            },
        });
    }, [currency, showSpinner]);


    return (<>
            { (showSpinner && isPending) && <div 
              className="spinner" /> }

          
            
            <PayPalButtons
                style={style}
                disabled={false}
                forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
                fundingSource={undefined}
                createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                    return actions.order
                        .create({
                            purchase_units: [
                                {
                                    amount: {
                                        currency_code: currency,
                                        value: amount,
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        })
                        .then((orderId) => {
                            return orderId;
                        });
                }}
                onApprove={function (data, actions) {
                    return actions.order.capture().then(function(){
                        alert("You have completed the transaction")
                    });
                }}
            />
            
        </>
    );
}

export default function Payments() {
    return (
        
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "750px", minHeight: "200px" }}>
            
            <PayPalScriptProvider
                options={{
                    'client-id': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
                    "disable-funding": "paylater",
                    components: "buttons",
                    currency: "USD"
                }
            
            }
            >
                <ButtonWrapper
                    currency={currency}
                    showSpinner={false}
                />
                
            </PayPalScriptProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image: PayPal Buttons]
[image: PayPal Popup]

Comment: please remove the screenshots of code in your questions and replace them with proper code blocks in text format. Changes to `amount` do not require the PayPal buttons to be re-rendered

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I removed the screenshots and added the proper code

Comment: So are variables like `amount` props, or constants? In the above code they are constants. If they were props with useState or similar then they can be used dynamically. Again `amount` does not belong in forceReRender

Comment: Furthermore, actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated, and should not be used in any new integrations. See the current standard integration guide at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ for information on having the createOrder and onApprove callback functions fetch from a backend that calls the v2/checkout/orders API

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to get it to work dynamically with your suggestions